# Clear the template in JS Bin

Tags: js-bin

If you click on the *Save as my template* link at `https://jsbin.com/` it will save the current page as my template and display it when I come back to the page later.

How do I undo that so that I get a clean slate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may sound stupid but removing the content in both windows left and right and saving it as an template creates a blank state.

If you want to have the original template back here's the data:

**JS**

```
if (document.getElementById('hello')) {
  document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'Hello World - this was inserted using JavaScript';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>​
```

Clearing your cookies for this site will also bring back this original template.

Comment: stupid is as stupid does sir.  That's what I did.  I just don't get why there isn't a button for that.